# angular-cli changed to @angular/cli - anybody knows why?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've been using angular-cli for a while now, and I've noticed the last few commits changed scripts referring to the name of the package.

It seems that angular-cli team changed its package name from [angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) to [@angular/cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli).

Are there any advantages for this way of naming a package other then being consist with angular2 naming system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is to keep the naming for all the Angular packages consistent. The same pattern is used for other official Angular Packages on npm such as material and flex-layout:

- @angular/material
- @angular/flex-layout

And of course the other core packages, for example:

- @angular/common
- @angular/compiler
- @angular/core

The @ sign is actually something npm is calling [npm-scope](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). The

> Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also
>   affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.

Answer (score 1):

Same path as they followed with angular2. With the next release they will go out of beta, hence the change to `@angular`. With angular2 that's also when they changed their naming. Not entirely sure about the philosophy behind it, but I guess they also want to have the two projects working closer together. Which reflects in the [cli-quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cli-quickstart.html) on their home page